# How to get user location using FB iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

Hereby my login scope for fb-login

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_location"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Process error
                NSLog(@"error %@",error);
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                // Handle cancellations
                NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            } else {
                if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                    // Do work
                    NSLog(@"%@",result);

                }
            }
        }];
```

I am using the following code to retrieve username, userid, email from facebook.

I can't retrieve an user's location. Help me out

```
 NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [parameters setValue:@"id,name,email,location" forKey:@"fields"];

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {

                 NSLog(@"%@",result objectForKey:@"name");
             }
         }];
```

Comment: does fb api provide location at all ?

Comment: Try with "user_location" instead of "location"

Comment: Having the exact same problem.  Btw, 'user_location' instead of 'location' didn't work for me.